# Change Modal button texts in Ant Design

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have the `Modal` with default button texts. I need to change them, but `okButtonProps.children` and `cancelButtonProps.children` don't work.

```
<Modal
  okButtonProps={{
    children: "Custom OK"
  }}
  cancelButtonProps={{
    children: "Custom cancel"
  }}
>
  Modal content
</Modal>
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-modal-okbuttonprops-and-cancelbuttonprops-issue-vmxck)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to use `okText` and `cancelText` property:

```js
    <Modal
      visible={true}
      okButtonProps={{
        children: "Custom OK"
      }}
      cancelButtonProps={{
        children: "Custom cancel"
      }}
      okText="Hello"
      cancelText="Ciao"
    />
```

`okButtonProps` and `cancelButtonProps` is to place `props` actions that will happen once `ok` button is pressed, or `cancel` button is pressed.

They are not for placing text, but for placing actions.

For placing text use `okText` and `cancelText`, just check the API:

https://ant.design/components/modal/#API

Comment: Select the answer as solved if it is, it helps others find solutions.